# Tensorflow object detection evaluation pycocotools missing

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, evaluation

Following the TF tutorial on pet object detection : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md

Ran locally : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md

The training seems to work well.

Trying to launch the evaluation process from the `tensorflow/models/research/` directory

```
python object_detection/eval.py \
    --logtostderr \
    --pipeline_config_path=${PATH_TO_YOUR_PIPELINE_CONFIG} \
    --checkpoint_dir=${PATH_TO_TRAIN_DIR} \
    --eval_dir=${PATH_TO_EVAL_DIR}
```

I got the following error

```
from pycocotools import coco \
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycocotools'
```

Had a look on coco API but I don't see any clear way to install it on Windows.

Any advice on how to get the evaluation running the simpliest way ?

---

More details about the error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "object_detection/eval.py", line 50, in <module>
from object_detection import evaluator
File "D:\models\research\object_detection\evaluator.py", line 27, in <module>
from object_detection.metrics import coco_evaluation
File "D:\models\research\object_detection\metrics\coco_evaluation.py", line 20, in <module>
from object_detection.metrics import coco_tools
File "D:\models\research\object_detection\metrics\coco_tools.py", line 47, in <module>
from pycocotools import coco ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycocotools'
```

Comment: Did you try `pip install git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#egg=pycocotools^&subdirectory=PythonAPI` (from https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/6)?

Comment: Nope, will try ^^

Comment: Some progress...

Got an error about the & character :
Le caractère perluète n’est pas autorisé. L’opérateur & est réservé à une utilisation future. Placez un caractère perluète entre guillemets doubles ("&") pour que ce symbole soit considéré comme une chaîne.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed

So I added quote...
Cloning working but stopped because Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 required. Will see If I can add it.

Comment: Did you try `pip install pycocotools`?

Answer (score 22):

This solved the same issue for me:

```
pip3 install -U scikit-image
pip3 install -U cython 
pip3 install "git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#egg=pycocotools&subdirectory=PythonAPI"
```

(and use pip instead of pip3 if you are using python 2.7)

Comment: According to https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN#installation, https://github.com/waleedka/coco is the proper fork for linux ---> `pip install "git+https://github.com/waleedka/coco.git#egg=pycocotools&subdirectory=PythonAPI"`

Answer (score 2):

Following command worked for me.

```
pip install pycocotools
```

Comment: For me too ! :-)

Answer (score 2):

It works for me with this just simple method. If you are windows, try to install pycocotools in windows version. With code in following:

```
pip install pycocotools-windows
```

With this method, you don't need to install any visual build tools. Hope this can help those who finding the ways of installing pycocotools.

Answer (score 1):

Could you post the full stack trace so we can see where pycocotools is being imported from? We're adding COCO support to the Tensorflow Object-Detection API (with a few other goodies), and will update the installation instructions soon.

Comment: Yes I will.
What do you mean by full stack trace ?
The result after eval.py or after pip install git+... ?

Comment: For the step that gives the following error:

from pycocotools import coco \ ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycocotools'

Could you post all of the details?

Comment: Just added more details with the full error message. Is it what you need to identify where pycocotools is being imported from ? Many thanks for your support.*

Comment: Download the [cocoapi](https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi) and run the python installation steps.

```
# From PythonAPI
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Does downloading the cocoapi and running the installation steps make sense if you are running in the Google ML cloud? Does cocoapi need to be included in the gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training command here?  https://github.com/datitran/object_detector_app/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_cloud.md

Comment: @Derek : don't have make with powershell, I'm under Windows environment :(. Cf comments higher with pip install git+...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it, but unfortunately for you, I am working on Ubuntu. But hopefully this helps someone else with the same issue:

First of all, you need to follow the steps that are described in the install guide of the object detection api. In my case though, that was not enough, I had the same problem as before. During the installation process described there, you download a github repository, specifically [this one.](https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi)

What I did next was to navigate to the folder cocoapi/PythonAPI and running

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Evaluation script seems to be working now.

Comment: Thanks for this report :-). Will take a look in the coming week.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
git clone https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi
```

Then in the PythonAPI directory, install library:

```
cd PythonAPI
python setup.py build_ext install
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows the sure way to do this is:

1. Install Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools from https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126 with default selection.
2. pip install git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#egg=pycocotools^&subdirectory=PythonAPI

Answer (score 0):

1. First open a command prompt and run

```
git clone https://github.com/pdollar/coco.git
```

2. Then move to this directory

```
cd coco/PythonAPI
```

3. And then edit the setup.py file in the coco/PythonAPI directory
   from this

```
extra_compile_args=['-Wno-cpp', '-Wno-unused-function', '-std=c99'],
```

to this

```
extra_compile_args=['-std=c99'],
```

then save

4. And then in the coco/PythonAPI directory, run

```
python setup.py install
```

Your problem should be solved

Answer (score 0):

The best and the easiest way to fix this error is to just use pip to install it

```
!pip install -q pycocotools
```

You can use pip3 if you have python3 and you are in Linux or mac